# DataTable.AsEnumerable().ToList(); min/max return invalid if data is int

Tags: c#, datatable

```
var list = ProcessedInformationTable.AsEnumerable().ToList();
                        var minValue = list.Min(v => v["Rank"]);
                        var maxValue = list.Max(v => v["Rank"]);
```

In the code above if I had the values of

ColumnA|Rank

Heart|9

Lung|10

minValue will return as 10 and maxvalue will return as 9.  My guess is because it's treated as a string even though every value is an int.  Is there a way around this?

Comment: Is Column data type `int` in the DataTable?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter i dont specify the datatable type because it comes from a sql query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't create a `List<T>` from the `DataTable`, that just doubles the required memory without any benefit. Use `Linq-To-DataSet` which is a subset of `Linq-To-Objects`.

Either the column is already of type `int`, then you have to cast it accodingly or it's actually `string`. Then you have to change that or use `ìnt.Parse` first:

```
var rows = ProcessedInformationTable.AsEnumerable();
int minValue = rows.Min(r => r.Field<int>("Rank"));
int maxValue = rows.Max(r => r.Field<int>("Rank"));
```

If it's string:

```
int minValue = rows.Min(r => int.Parse(r.Field<string>("Rank")));
int maxValue = rows.Max(r => int.Parse(r.Field<string>("Rank")));
```

Comment: What is "equiwed" memory?  If it's a typo, not sure what of.

Answer (score 0):

Provided that your Rank column is an integer and doesn't contain nulls:

```
var list = ProcessedInformationTable.AsEnumerable().ToList();
var minValue = list.Min(v => (int)v["Rank"]);
var maxValue = list.Max(v => (int)v["Rank"]);
```

`v["Rank"]` is most likely casting as a string using the built-in `object.ToString()` when evaluating.